# How to lift multiple values in state from a form submission?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

My goal is to take an input value and a radio input's value and lift their state to the parent component`App.js` when the form is submitted. I am using two onChange events and when the form is submitted the values are propped and handle by individual functions in app.js. That is where the problem is because I need to pass two value parameters to the handleNote function. I know I am on the wrong path here. Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Header from "./Header";

//app.js

class App extends Component {

  handleColor = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      noteColor: value
    });
  };

  handleNote = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      noteTitle: value
      // noteColor: value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header handleNote={this.handleNote} handleColor={this.handleColor} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

//Header.js

class Header extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      note: "",
      noteColor: "white"
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // lifting state to handleNote()
    this.props.handleNote(this.state.note);

    // have this.state.noteColor lift within handleNote()
    this.props.handleColor(this.state.noteColor);

    this.setState({
      note: ""
    });
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      note: e.target.value
      // noteColor should be here
    });
  };

  handleColor = e => {
    this.setState({
      noteColor: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="name" className="sr-only">
          Type anything that you need to know for later...
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="note"
          placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.note}
          required
        />
        <div className="radio-container">
          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            White
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleColor}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="white"
            id="white"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Yellow
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleColor}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="yellow"
            id="yellow"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Red
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleColor}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="red"
            id="red"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Green
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleColor}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="green"
            id="green"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Blue
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleColor}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="blue"
            id="blue"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Purple
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleColor}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="purple"
            id="purple"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *over-complicating* it a bit. I would simplify it into something like this:

## App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './styles.css';
import Header from './Header';

class App extends Component {
  handleNote = ({ note, noteColor }) => {
    console.log('note', note);
    console.log('notecolor', noteColor);
    this.setState({
      noteTitle: note,
      noteColor,
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log('this.state', this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <Header handleNote={this.handleNote} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

## Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './styles.css';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const initialState = {
      note: '',
      noteColor: 'white',
    }

    this.state = initialState;

    this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          this.props.handleNote(this.state);

          // reset local state
          this.setState(initialState);
        }}
      >
        <label htmlFor="name" className="sr-only">
          Type anything that you need to know for later...
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="note"
          placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.note}
          required
        />
        <div className="radio-container">
          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            White
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            type="radio"
            name="noteColor"
            value="white"
            id="white"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Yellow
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleColor}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="yellow"
            id="yellow"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Red
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleColor}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="red"
            id="red"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Green
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleColor}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="green"
            id="green"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Blue
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleColor}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="blue"
            id="blue"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Purple
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleColor}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="purple"
            id="purple"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Thanks it works, could you explain what exactly is going on please? I understand how we are grabbing the values' names with handleChange. We don't need to bind handleChange because it is an arrow function correct? The onSubmit function is now in the form where we prop to handleNote as well?

Comment: Oh, yes, you are correct about binding (it's been awhile sense I've used classes). Yeah, so basically the onSubmit function is just inline in the form element, and it passes the entire state from Header up to App using handleNote(). I'm using destructuring for the parameters if you are not familiar with the syntax. If you have any other questions let me know.

Comment: Thanks again. One question, I use the setState method in the onSubmit function where I set the state of noteTitle: ' '. I am trying to clear the input on submit and when I submit, in my dev tools the noteTitle state is being set to ' ' when I submit, but the input is not being cleared.

Comment: @seandaniel I just updated my answer. I added an initialState variable which is used at the start and then again inside onSubmit() to reset the state.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have your handleSubmit function created and assigned to the onSubmit on the form but nothing is starting the function. Add
`<button type="submit">Click me</button>` in the form to trigger handleSubmit.

Comment: My form still submits without a submit button because I am getting this.state.note in app.js. I want this.state.note and this.state.noteColor.

Comment: And the form submits after what action?

Comment: Hitting enter on your keyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Header from "./Header";

//app.js

class App extends Component {


  handleNote = (title,color) => {
    this.setState({
      noteTitle: title
      noteColor: color,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header handleNote={this.handleNote} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

//Header.js

class Header extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      note: "",
      noteColor: "white"
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // lifting state to handleNote()
    this.props.handleNote(this.state.note,this.state.noteColor);
    this.setState({
      note: ""
    });
  };


  handleChange = (name,e) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="name" className="sr-only">
          Type anything that you need to know for later...
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="note"
          placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
          onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange("note",e)}
          value={this.state.note}
          required
        />
        <div className="radio-container">
          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            White
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange("noteColor",e)}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="white"
            id="white"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Yellow
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange("noteColor",e)}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="yellow"
            id="yellow"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Red
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange("noteColor",e)}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="red"
            id="red"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Green
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange("noteColor",e)}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="green"
            id="green"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Blue
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange("noteColor",e)}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="blue"
            id="blue"
          />

          <label htmlFor="yellow" className="sr-only">
            Purple
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange("noteColor",e)}
            type="radio"
            name="color"
            value="purple"
            id="purple"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: hope this is what you want !

Comment: e is undefined for the onChanges in Header's render()

Comment: my bad ,I have modified that. I was not passing that event in function params.